# Display only relevant information from SQLite database in textView

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have set up a simple table of subject information that has 3 columns: id (increments automatically), subject, and level. Level ranges between 1 and 3. If, on a certain activity I want to display all of the subjects of level 2 in separate textViews, how would I go about implementing this?

Below is my code for the database activity:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "NCEA_app";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;



//table
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "subject_table";
public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
public static final String COL_2 = "SUBJECT";
public static final String COL_3 = "LEVEL";

public static final String CREATE_TABLE = "create table " + TABLE_NAME +" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,SUBJECT TEXT,LEVEL INTEGER)";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean insertSubject(String subject,String level) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2,subject);
    contentValues.put(COL_3,level);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null ,contentValues);
    if(result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

public Cursor getAllData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_NAME,null);
    return res;
}
}
```

I would assume I need to loop through my whole database and find every subject with the right level, but I am new to SQL and don't know how this would be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a method like this for getting the subject data from database in Your DatabaseHelper Class

```
public Cursor getSubjectDataForParticularLevel(int level){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT SUBJECT"+TABLE_NAME+" WHERE COL_3 = "+level, null);
        return cursor;
    }
```

and you can get your data in Activity like this

```
 DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper = DatabaseHelper(this);
    ArrayList<String> subjectList = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor cursor = mDatabaseHelper.getSubjectDataForParticularLevel(2); 
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
      do{
        //your Subject list
        subjectList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("SUBJECT")));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
```

Comment: Hi @sunil kushwah. Thanks for your answer. If you have time would you mind telling me how I'd convert that list into a list of textViews on the actual activity? Thanks

Comment: why u want to create list of text views, u just use single text view and set text like this "subjet1\n\nsubject2\n\nsubject3..." it will give u list type structure.

Comment: I was wanting to create a list and then make each of them a seperate button, but can I do that with a single text view?

Comment: no u can't do this with a single textview for that u have to use either listview or recycler view

Comment: just go through this simple example u will get your  answer https://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-listview-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

you have to get result for level to only by using following:

```
public Cursor getLevel2Data(int level) {
         SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
         Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_NAME + " where " + COL_3 + "="+level,null);
         return res;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sorry if this is a dumb question as I'm really new to this, but what kind of information is returned? Is it returning a list of the subjects, or a more refined table?

Comment: Keep in mind that if any values come from user input, building a SQL query using string concatenation is susceptible to SQL injection. To be safe, you should use bound parameters instead.

Comment: @Roonil The result is a `Cursor`. There are many tutorials online about SQLite and Android. Take a look and see what you can learn about database cursors.

Comment: Hi @Code-Apprentice. Thanks, needed to know what to look up :) The values do come from user input. How would I use bound parameters in this case?

Comment: @Roonil Instead of using `rawQuery()`, use `query()`. The `selection` parameter, should be something like `"WHERE " + COL_3 + " = ?"`. And then provide the values in the `selectionArgs` parameter. Note that concatenating the column name is safe as long as it is not provided by the user.

Comment: @Roonil For more details, google "sqlite bound parameters"

Comment: the above query will crash... use `db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_NAME + " where " + COL_3 + "=2",null);`
         return res;` just use a space before where ..

Comment: @SantanuSur Which is another reason to use `query()` instead of `rawQuery()`.

Comment: use `cursorLoader` with `contentProvider` thats the best because the data is loaded `asynchronously` isntead of hampering thr `UI thread`

Answer (score 0):

Write a separate function in your Database class for querying only Level 2 entries. `SQL` query should be like

```
Select * From Table_name WHERE LEVEL = 2;
```